# How to implement Desktop notifications while installation of my application

Tags: windows, notifications, nsis, desktop

I have a c++ based desktop application which uses nsis scripts for installation process. I need to implement windows desktop notifications while the app is in installation process. Is there any possible to do so using nsis scripts or cmd commands.Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Having a notification icon in a installer probably breaks some UI guideline but if you really must you can try the [NotifyIcon plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NotifyIcon_plug-in).